# How huge timeline services work with database?

Tags: sql, database, twitter, structure, timeline

Web services which have timelines like twitter or facebook, how do they work with that huge data?

Twitter for example, tweets are not one->one but one->multiple.
If I think about the structure of it, it will be like this.

1. Tom tweets "hello world", the system insert a new record like 
   '"hello world", fr:"Tom"'
2. Mike who is one of Tom's followers login to the service, the system check out new tweets of his friends, then finds
   '"hello world", fr:"Tom"'

This is very simple, but I bet it doesn't work on services with huge users, because if Mike follows 10,000 people, the system has to continue doing step #2 10,000 times, it takes a long time.
(select * from tweets where fm = [FRIENDS x 10,000])

Then how about this way.

1. Tom tweets "hello world", the system check Tom's followers list, and insert new records
   '"hello world", fr:"Tom", to:"Mike"'
   '"hello world", fr:"Tom", to:"Nick"'
   '"hello world", fr:"Tom", to:"Ken"'
   ... x numbers of followers
2. Mike logins, the system runs like
   (select * from tweets where to = "Mike")

In this way, Mike won't wait for the system response for a long time, but if Tom has 1,000,000 followers, the system has to insert 1,000,000 records right after Tom's tweet. Tom might tweet 5 secs after the previous one, then another 1,000,000 records.

I am interested in this topic.
If you know how they make it, please teach me, and even if you don't know an exact way, sharing your ideas would be so thankful.

Answer (score 1):

If you set it up like these 3 tables:

```
user
user_tweet
user_friend
```

You can store a user in the user table, a tweet in the user_tweet table, and friend of a user (which is of course another user) can be stored in the user_friend (relational) table.

The query you need would be like:

```
select user_tweet.* from user_tweet 
join user on user_tweet.user_id = user.id
where user.id = @currentLoggedOnUserId
```

This will give yo a list of all the tweets from the users that are related to the logged on user. When users make friends a record is added to the user_friend table (with the user id and the the friend id).